# Why is (eq (car '('x)) 'x) => nil

Tags: quote

### Context

In `notmuch` there is the a function that reads the `:search-type` property from a list and compares it to a symbol. This comparison is always `nil` for `'tree'` / `'unthreaded`, even though `saved-search` is set correctly (or not - that is the question).

A reduced problem follows below.

```lisp
; ...
            (cond
             ((eq (plist-get saved-search :search-type) 'tree)
              `(lambda () (notmuch-tree ',query)))
             ((eq (plist-get saved-search :search-type) 'unthreaded)
              `(lambda () (notmuch-unthreaded ',query)))
             (t
              `(lambda () (notmuch-search ',query ',oldest-first)))))
; ...
```

### Reduced Problem

The following minimal test shows the problem. I would expect that this `sexp` evaluates to `'t` though it evaluates to `nil`.

```lisp
(eq (plist-get `(:search-type 'tree) :search-type) 'tree)
```

This can be reduced to

```lisp
(eq (car '('tree)) 'tree)    ; => nil
(eq 'tree 'tree)             ; => t
```

### Work Around

Using `intern` to create the item in the list works:

```lisp
(eq (car `(,(intern "tree"))) 'tree)    ; => t
```

## Question

According to my understanding of the `eq` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Equality-Predicates.html) both `'tree` instances in `(eq (car '('tree)) 'tree)` *should* be the same object.

Why is this not the case?

## Emacs Version

I am using `doom` (if that is relevant) which compiles the elisp to native code (if that is of any help).

```
"GNU Emacs 28.0.91 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.20, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-18"
```

Comment: `(eq (car '(tree)) 'tree)  ; => t`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short story, you have one extra `'` in there which is confusing you.

Long story: The single–quote character precedes any expression which is to be treated literally. The reader turns it into a cons containing the symbole `quote` and whatever it reads afterwards. So `'42` would be read as `(quote 42)`. Later, when what you have read in gets evaluated, the evaluator looks for this `quote` symbol and removes it, but doesn’t evaluate whatever was left. So if you type `tree`, it gets read as the symbol `tree` and the evaluator looks for a variable named `tree` to find the value. On the other hand, if you typed `'tree` then the reader returns `(quote tree)` and the evaluator unpacks it to just the symbol `tree`, and then doesn’t do anything else; it doesn’t look for a variable called tree.

Ok, so `'('tree)` is read as `(quote ((quote tree))`. The evaluator then unpacks it to just be `((quote tree))`. It is a list with one element, and that element is a list with two elements, `quote` and `tree`. Now you call `car` on this list, which gives you the first element. That element is the list `(quote tree)`, which is indeed not `eq` to the symbol `tree` that you wanted.

Part of the confusion is that if you evaluate `(car '('tree))` in the scratch buffer, it will print out `'tree`. It is easy to overlook the extra `'` there! It might be easier if it printed out `(quote tree)` instead, but maybe that would be confusing for other reasons.